# Why jboss uses deprecated DOMSerializerImpl org.apache.xerces 2.12.0.SP03

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, marshalling, infinispan

I've got an issue while deploing with putting key value into the infinispan cache some object
`ISPN000559: Cannot marshall 'class org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject': org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException`

from the stacktrace I see that it calls `org.apache.xerces@2.12.0.SP03//org.apache.xml.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl.writeToString(DOMSerializerImpl.java:518)` from the deprecated class, but as I understand it should use `xalan serializer 2.7.2` instead

when I trying to serialize it from our app, it uses the correct serializer using this code from xercesImpl-2.12.2 CoreDomImplementationImpl.java

```
public LSSerializer createLSSerializer() {
        try {
            Class serializerClass = ObjectFactory.findProviderClass(
                "org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3.LSSerializerImpl",
                ObjectFactory.findClassLoader(), true);
            return (LSSerializer) serializerClass.newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        // Fall back to Xerces' deprecated serializer if 
        // the Xalan based serializer is unavailable.
        return new DOMSerializerImpl();
    }
```

we call it like this

```
    public static @Null
    String documentToString(@Null Document document) {
        if (document == null) {
            return null;
        }
        DOMImplementationLS domImplementation = (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();
        LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementation.createLSSerializer();

        String result = lsSerializer.writeToString(document);
      
        return result;
    }
```

please help me to understand why incorrect serializer is used while deploy and how to fix it;
needed library xalan-2.7.2 is present in WEB-INF\lib\

orgWildflyVersion = '26.1.2.Final'
infinispanVersion = '13.0.10.Final'

Comment: trying to add  <module name="org.apache.xalan"/> to jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Comment: adding <module name="org.apache.xalan"/> to jboss-deployment-structure.xml didn't help(

Comment: did you find a solution?  I am having a similar issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76054209/infinispan-cannot-write-cache-to-file-marshallableuserobject-notserializable