# Infinispan cannot write cache to file - MarshallableUserObject - NotSerializableException

Tags: java, caching, wildfly, load-balancing, infinispan

I am using wildFly22 with Java11 and am trying to configure Infinispan cache.

**distributable-web.xml**

```
<distributable-web xmlns="urn:jboss:distributable-web:2.0">
    <infinispan-session-management cache-container="web" cache="corpapp-session-cache-web" granularity="SESSION">
        <primary-owner-affinity/>
    </infinispan-session-management>
</distributable-web>
```

**standalone-ha.xml**

```
        <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" marshaller="PROTOSTREAM" modules="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="corpapp-session-cache-web">
                <file-store path="corpapp-cache" passivation="false" purge="false" shared="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="passivation">
                <expiration interval="0"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="sso">
                <expiration interval="0"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
```

e.g. if I set the marshaller to:

```
marshaller="PROTOSTREAM"
```

it gets this:

```
WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (default task-2)
ISPN000559: Cannot marshall 'class org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject': java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.12.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.writeKnownObject(RiverMarshaller.java:990
```

e.g. if I set the marshaller to:

```
marshaller="JBOSS"
```

it gets this:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023:
Exception handling request to /corporateInterface/login.do:
org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException:
org.infinispan.commons.marshall.MarshallingException: org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.SessionAccessMetaDataKey
```

**More Info**

Here is the stack trace:

```
WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (default task-2) ISPN000559: Cannot marshall 'class org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject': java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.12.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.writeKnownObject(RiverMarshaller.java:990)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river@2.0.12.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:217)
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.12.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at ...
    at org.jboss.marshalling@2.0.12.Final//org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.jboss@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.jboss.JBossByteBufferMarshaller.writeTo(JBossByteBufferMarshaller.java:92)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.spi@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.spi.ByteBufferMarshaller.write(ByteBufferMarshaller.java:55)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.spi@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.spi.ByteBufferMarshalledValue.getBuffer(ByteBufferMarshalledValue.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream.FunctionalScalarMarshaller.writeTo(FunctionalScalarMarshaller.java:169)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream.DefaultProtoStreamWriter.writeObjectNoTag(DefaultProtoStreamWriter.java:51)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream.ProtoStreamWriter.writeObject(ProtoStreamWriter.java:60)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream.TypedObjectMarshaller.writeTo(TypedObjectMarshaller.java:60)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream.AnyMarshaller.writeTo(AnyMarshaller.java:76)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream.AnyMarshaller.writeTo(AnyMarshaller.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream.ProtoStreamMarshaller.write(ProtoStreamMarshaller.java:50)
    at org.infinispan.protostream@4.4.1.Final//org.infinispan.protostream.impl.ProtobufTagMarshallerDelegate.marshall(ProtobufTagMarshallerDelegate.java:27)
    at org.infinispan.protostream@4.4.1.Final//org.infinispan.protostream.ProtobufUtil.write(ProtobufUtil.java:70)
    at org.infinispan.protostream@4.4.1.Final//org.infinispan.protostream.ProtobufUtil.writeTo(ProtobufUtil.java:75)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.marshalling.protostream.ProtoStreamByteBufferMarshaller.writeTo(ProtoStreamByteBufferMarshaller.java:94)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.AbstractUserMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractUserMarshaller.java:62)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.objectToBuffer(AbstractMarshaller.java:107)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.objectToByteBuffer(AbstractMarshaller.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.objectToByteBuffer(AbstractMarshaller.java:76)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.core.impl.DelegatingUserMarshaller.objectToByteBuffer(DelegatingUserMarshaller.java:58)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject$Marshaller.write(MarshallableUserObject.java:150)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.MarshallableUserObject$Marshaller.write(MarshallableUserObject.java:100)
    at org.infinispan.protostream@4.4.1.Final//org.infinispan.protostream.impl.ProtobufTagMarshallerDelegate.marshall(ProtobufTagMarshallerDelegate.java:27)
    at org.infinispan.protostream@4.4.1.Final//org.infinispan.protostream.WrappedMessage.writeMessage(WrappedMessage.java:301)
    at org.infinispan.protostream@4.4.1.Final//org.infinispan.protostream.WrappedMessage.write(WrappedMessage.java:242)
    at org.infinispan.protostream@4.4.1.Final//org.infinispan.protostream.ProtobufUtil.toWrappedStream(ProtobufUtil.java:162)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.objectToByteBuffer(AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.java:75)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.protostream.impl.AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.objectToBuffer(AbstractInternalProtoStreamMarshaller.java:62)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.MarshallableEntryImpl.marshall(MarshallableEntryImpl.java:230)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.MarshallableEntryImpl.<init>(MarshallableEntryImpl.java:41)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.marshall.persistence.impl.MarshalledEntryFactoryImpl.create(MarshalledEntryFactoryImpl.java:65)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.persistence.spi.MarshallableEntryFactory.create(MarshallableEntryFactory.java:95)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheWriterInterceptor.marshalledEntry(CacheWriterInterceptor.java:471)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheWriterInterceptor.storeEntry(CacheWriterInterceptor.java:451)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheWriterInterceptor.storeEntry(CacheWriterInterceptor.java:444)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheWriterInterceptor.lambda$visitDataWriteCommandToStore$14(CacheWriterInterceptor.java:487)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextThenApply(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheWriterInterceptor.visitDataWriteCommandToStore(CacheWriterInterceptor.java:480)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheWriterInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(CacheWriterInterceptor.java:186)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.asyncInvokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:232)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheLoaderInterceptor.visitDataCommand(CacheLoaderInterceptor.java:211)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheLoaderInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(CacheLoaderInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.asyncInvokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:232)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.EntryWrappingInterceptor.setSkipRemoteGetsAndInvokeNextForDataCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:760)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.EntryWrappingInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(EntryWrappingInterceptor.java:346)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndFinally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.lambda$nonTxLockAndInvokeNext$3(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:318)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.SyncInvocationStage.andHandle(SyncInvocationStage.java:69)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.nonTxLockAndInvokeNext(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:313)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitNonTxDataWriteCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.visitDataWriteCommand(NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.AbstractLockingInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(AbstractLockingInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.updateStoreStatistics(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.CacheMgmtInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(CacheMgmtInterceptor.java:211)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNext(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.handleDefault(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.DDAsyncInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand(DDAsyncInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.commands.write.PutKeyValueCommand.acceptVisitor(PutKeyValueCommand.java:63)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.BaseAsyncInterceptor.invokeNextAndExceptionally(BaseAsyncInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.InvocationContextInterceptor.visitCommand(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.interceptors.impl.AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.invoke(AsyncInterceptorChainImpl.java:244)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.InvocationHelper.doInvoke(InvocationHelper.java:297)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.InvocationHelper.invoke(InvocationHelper.java:101)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.InvocationHelper.invoke(InvocationHelper.java:83)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.put(CacheImpl.java:1293)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.DecoratedCache.put(DecoratedCache.java:678)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.DecoratedCache.put(DecoratedCache.java:537)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.put(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:449)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.EncoderCache.put(EncoderCache.java:698)
    at org.infinispan@12.1.7.Final//org.infinispan.cache.impl.AbstractDelegatingCache.put(AbstractDelegatingCache.java:449)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan.CacheEntryMutator.mutate(CacheEntryMutator.java:59)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache.session.coarse.CoarseSessionAttributes.close(CoarseSessionAttributes.java:99)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache.session.CompositeSession.close(CompositeSession.java:77)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache.session.ValidSession.close(ValidSession.java:88)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache.session.ConcurrentSessionManager$ConcurrentSession.closeSession(ConcurrentSessionManager.java:159)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache.session.ConcurrentSessionManager$1.accept(ConcurrentSessionManager.java:55)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache.session.ConcurrentSessionManager$1.accept(ConcurrentSessionManager.java:52)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.cache@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.ee.cache.ConcurrentManager$2.apply(ConcurrentManager.java:66)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.cache@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.ee.cache.ConcurrentManager$2.apply(ConcurrentManager.java:57)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1932)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.cache@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.ee.cache.ConcurrentManager$3.run(ConcurrentManager.java:88)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.web.cache.session.ConcurrentSessionManager$ConcurrentSession.close(ConcurrentSessionManager.java:190)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession.requestDone(DistributableSession.java:120)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.updateSessionAccessTime(ServletContextImpl.java:987)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:211)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:130)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear//org.apache.struts.util.SecureRequestUtils.checkSsl(SecureRequestUtils.java:614)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear//org.apache.struts.action.SecureTilesRequestProcessor.processPreprocess(SecureTilesRequestProcessor.java:104)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear//org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:182)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear//org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1962)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear//org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:446)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear.corporateInterface-3.10.war//application.configuration.cache.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:28)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear.corporateInterface-3.10.war//application.configuration.cache.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:21)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear.corporateInterface-3.10.war//application.configuration.logging.LoggerFilter.doFilter(LoggerFilter.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear.corporateInterface-3.10.war//com.travellinck.protection.InputProtectionFilter.doFilter(InputProtectionFilter.java:30)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear.corporateInterface-3.10.war//com.travellinck.travelIT.admin.sessiontracker.LoggedInUsersFilter.doFilter(LoggedInUsersFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear.corporateInterface-3.10.war//com.travellinck.notes.filter.UpdateNotesFilter.doFilter(UpdateNotesFilter.java:75)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear.corporateInterface-3.10.war//com.travellinck.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:41)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear.corporateInterface-3.10.war//application.configuration.compression.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:28)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.corporateEar-3.10.ear.corporateInterface-3.10.war//corptravweb.security.TLJaasAdaptorFilter.doFilter(TLJaasAdaptorFilter.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.17.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.9.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:280)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@25.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:260)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.12.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in object java.lang.Object@284f63da
    in object java.util.HashMap@f6e39bcd
    in object java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@16d76032
```

Comment: This mentions the `NotSerializableException` error, but doesn't provide a solution. http://www.dataforte.net/listing/infinispan/generated-html/user_guide/user_guide.html

Comment: I would assume a fix would be to make the object concerned serializable. The reported error indicates that a `java.lang.Object` is not serializable. There is no indication which object.